# Wrapper function for pandas applymap

Tags: python, pandas, scikit-learn

I am using sklearn.preprocessing.FunctionTransformer with some custom functions.

```
def enumerate_virus_scanned(virus_scanned: str) -> int:
    return 1 if not pd.isnull(virus_scanned) else 0

def enumerate_priority(priority: str) -> int:
    try:
        return int(re.search(r'\d+', priority).group(0))
    except (AttributeError, TypeError):
        return 0

def enumerate_encoding(encoding: str) -> int:
    content_transfer_encoding = {
        "na":  0,
        "base64": 1,
        "quoted-printable": 2,
        "8bit": 3,
        "7bit": 4,
        "binary": 5
    }
    try:
        return content_transfer_encoding[encoding.lower()]
    except (AttributeError, KeyError):
        return 0
```

As you may notice, these functions take a scalar as an input, but in the FunctionTransformer call, the DataFrame is passed as an input. Thus, I need to use the pd.DataFrame.applymap() method for each transformer.

```
virus_scanned_transformer, priority_transformer, encoding_transformer = (
    FunctionTransformer(lambda df: df.applymap(func)) for func in
    [enumerate_virus_scanned, enumerate_priority, enumerate_encoding]
)
```

However, this does not work. I do not want to convert the functions to call `df.applymap()` inside like that:

```
def enumerate_virus_scanned(df: pd.DataFrame) -> pd.DataFrame:
    return df.applymap(lambda x: 1 if not pd.isnull(x) else 0)
```

Is there any possibility to create a wrapper with a decorator, that will automatically call `df.applymap()` inside while calling the function transforming a scalar itself?

```
def transformer_wrapper(func):
    def wrap(*args, **kwargs):
        return df.applymap(func)
    return wrap

@transformer_wrapper
def enumerate_virus_scanned(virus_scanned: str) -> int:
    return 1 if not pd.isnull(virus_scanned) else 0
```

Maybe there is a better solution for that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your decorator is fairly close, just need to extract `df` as the first positional argument:

```py
from functools import wraps
import pandas as pd
from numpy import nan

def applymap_wrap(func):
    @wraps(func)
    def wrapper(df, *args, **kwargs):
        return df.applymap(func, *args, **kwargs)

    return wrapper

@applymap_wrap
def enumerate_virus_scanned(virus_scanned: str) -> int:
    return 1 if not pd.isnull(virus_scanned) else 0

# ---

df = DataFrame({
    "x": [ 10, nan, 20, 30, nan], 
    "y": [nan, nan,  1,  2,   3]
})

print(enumerate_virus_scanned(df))
   x  y
0  1  0
1  0  0
2  1  1
3  1  1
4  0  1
```

---

But on the other hand, why not use `DataFrame` level methods? Using approaches like `DataFrame.isnull()` is much faster than `DataFrame.applymap(lambda x: …)`

```py
print(df.notnull().astype(int))
   x  y
0  1  0
1  0  0
2  1  1
3  1  1
4  0  1
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your help! Now I see where I made the mistake with my wrapper - I could not see the appropriate context. Also, thanks for the remark about DataFrame-level methods. Frankly speaking I didn't take them into consideration as faster ones.

Comment: Definitely! `.applymap` (and any of the `.apply` methods) are essentially a Python for-loop under the hood iterating over each row, and then each value. This is great if you have a highly custom user-defined function. But if you're performing operations already baked into `pandas` or `numpy` you'll typically get a speed-up by using them.

Comment: Also, if this answer solved your problem, make sure to select it as correct so that others with the same (or similar) question can find it easily!